# If $X:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\times E\to E$ is a stochatic flow, is $\kappa_t(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[X^x_t\in B\right]$ a semigroup?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators, stochastic-pde

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space, $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space and $X:\Omega\times[0,\infty)\times E\to E$ be a *stochastic flow*, i.e. $X$ is $(\mathcal A\otimes\mathcal B([0,\infty))\otimes\mathcal E,\mathcal E)$-measurable and $X(\omega,\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;)$ is a [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(mathematics)#Formal_definition) for all $\omega\in\Omega$. Now let $$X^x_t:=X(\;\cdot\;,t,x)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,x)\in[0,\infty)\times E.$$ It's easy to see that $$\kappa_t(x,B):=\operatorname P\left[X^x_t\in B\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$$ is a Markov kernel and $$(\kappa_tf)(x):=\int\kappa(x,{\rm d}y)f(y)=\operatorname E\left[f(X^x_t)\right]\tag1$$ for all $\mathcal E$-measurable $f:E\to[0,\infty)$ for all $t\ge0$.

> **Question 1**: Can we show that $(\kappa_t)_{t\ge0}$ is a semigroup, i.e.$^1$ $\kappa_s\kappa_t=\kappa_{s+t}$ for all $s,t\ge0$?
>
> **Question 2**: Assuming that $E$ is a $\mathbb R$-Banach space, $\mathcal E=\mathcal B(E)$ and $X(\omega,t,\;\cdot\;)$ is continuously Fréchet differentiable for all $(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times[0,\infty)$, are we able to show that $\kappa_tf$ is continuously Fréchet differentiable for all continuously Fréchet differentiable $f:E\to\mathbb R$ and $t\ge0$?

*Regarding question 1*: Let $s,t\ge0$. By the flow property, we know that $$X^{X^x_s}_t=X^x_{s+t}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in E\tag2$$ and hence $$(\kappa_s\kappa_t)(x,B)=\operatorname E\left[\kappa_t(X^x_s,B)\right]=\operatorname E\left[\left.\operatorname P\left[X^y_t\in B\right]\right|_{y=X^x_s}\right]\tag3$$ for all $(x,B)\in E\times\mathcal E$.

*Regarding question 2*: If $f:E\to\mathbb R$ is Fréchet differentiable, then $E\ni x\mapsto f(X^x_t(\omega))$ is clearly Fréchet differentiable by the chain rule for all $(\omega,t)\in\Omega\times[0,\infty)$. So, I guess the desired claim boils down to a suitable application of the dominated convergence theorem.

---

$^1$ $\kappa_s\kappa_t$ denotes the [composition of kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Composition_of_kernels).

Comment: If I calculate correctly, $$\kappa_s \kappa_t(x,B) = \int \mathbb{P}[X_t^y \in B] (X_s^x)_* \mathbb{P}(dy) = \int \mathbb{P}[X(\cdot, X_s^x(\omega_1), t) \in B] \mathbb{P}(d\omega_1) = \iint 1_B[X(\omega_2, X_s^x(\omega_1), t)] \mathbb{P}(d\omega_1) \mathbb{P}(d \omega_2)$$
so I expect to need to know more than the flow property $\omega$-by-$\omega$ for the first question. Why do you expect this to be true?

Comment: @RhysSteele I'm not necessarily expecting this, but I wondered whether it holds (at least under a suitable further assumption) since stochastic flows naturally occurre, for example, as solutions of S(P)DEs and we are clearly interested in their transition kernels.

Comment: In those settings you usually have the extra ingredient that the solution up to time $s+t$ is the same as the solution at time $t$ of the S(P)DE started at the solution up to time $s$ which is exactly the ingredient that gives you this property.

Comment: @RhysSteele Yes, sure. How'd you write this property down for the flow in the question?

Comment: The only natural formulation I can think of in terms of the flow is just the result of your first question.

Comment: @RhysSteele Do you have an idea for the second question?